# Compatibility of Data Tools and Visual Studio version

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I got VS 2017 15.8.1 version installed and a legacy SSIS package created and run in VS 2012 version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5. So basically two VS instances on one machine. I also installed SSDT 15.4.0 version for VS 2017. My app saves .csv file on the server, makes a call to SQL Server 2016 which invokes SSIS packages and passes the address of .csv file to it. SSIS processes the file and saves data to the database. All this is working correctly, however, instead of displaying the uploaded file on page as a link the UI throws the following error.

> "Error: 2019-05-09 12:06:03.61, Code: 0xC000F427, Source:
>   SCR_Chk_UploadTypes, Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL
>   Server Data Tools you must install SCR_Chk_UploadTypes of Integration
>   Services or higher.,End Error,DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1)."

Any ideas what "SCR_Chk_UploadTypes" is? I'm guessing it might have some relation to SSDT and VS compatibility.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas what "SCR_Chk_UploadTypes" is? I'm guessing it might have
>   some relation to SSDT and VS compatibility.

I imagine that is either the name of a connection manager or a Data Source in the data flow(s). Can you post a screenshot?

With respect to the error itself, please note that Microsoft requires a package to target a specific version of SQL Server.

The package that runs in VS2012 can only target SQL Server 2012.

Starting with VS2015, Microsoft introduced the concept of Server targeting. By default, when creating a package in VS2017 the targeted SQL Server will be SQL Server 2017. Have you confirmed that the SQL Server version that the package is targeting is SQL Server 2016?

[For more information on targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53562698/4630376)

Comment: @J Weezy, I'm setting up a local environment with the VS and SQL Server versions mentioned in the first post. So for me it's VS 2012, 2017, and SQL Server 2016. This combination throws an error even though it partially does the work. However, the prod and test environments have SQL Server 2012 installed. According to your other post the SSIS package created in VS 2012 is defaulted to work against SQL Server 2012 and this might be an issue.

Comment: Disregard using VS2012 for now. You can do all of your work in VS2017. When you want to run against Prod and Test then you will target the package to SQL 2012. When you want to test against your local then target the package to SQL Server 2016. You should really keep all of your SQL Server environments in alignment so as to avoid these issues.